# POST Request Parameter Loss

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2, websphere

Client Code

```
function Call() 
{
    var value = $('input[name=form]:checked').val();
    if (typeof(value)=='undefined')
    {
        alert('Select One Record');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#bean\\.id").val(value.split("@@")[0]);
        var id = $("#bean\\.id").val();
        $.post("search.do", {'id': id},
        function(data){

        });
    }
}
<s:hidden name="bean.id" id="bean.id" />
<s:iterator var="form" value="#request.list" status="offset">
<input type="radio" name="form" value="${form.id}@@${form.status}"></input>
</s:iterator>
```

Server Code
Struts2 config XML

```
<action name="search" class="<action name>" method="search">
    <result name="success" type="json">
        <param name="includeProperties">returnString</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Java Action Function

```
public String search() throws Exception
{
    String id_server = context.getRequest().getParameter("id");
    // Do some stuff    
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Using Websphere 8.5.0.4.

It seems that sometimes the request parameter is not existed.
(id_server=null)
Does anyone have any idea why this happen?
I have other places using very similar code without problem.

I have failed to re-produce the problem. But my testing environment is Websphere 8.5.5.4.
I am not sure if this is the Websphere problem as the problem area is using 8.5.0.4 (Production environment).

Does anyone have any idea with this problem? Mainly I want to know the reason as I may need to explain.
Many Thanks

Comment: Did you check in all the browsers is it same behaviour ?

Comment: You can assume (And I believe) that all my users are using IE9.

Comment: Simple create an `id` variable in your action with getter/setter and stop using `getParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

By default servers put restriction on size of post request like in tomcat by default it is 2mb. If post request size exceeds this size, request parameters are discarded by server. You may check https://serverfault.com/questions/311610/how-to-increase-the-size-of-http-post-request-in-websphere to change it for websphere.

Comment: Not possible. The id is only a short integer length <10. BTW my application has already handled the request size up to 50MB+